# What is the correct syntax to combine multiple parameter expansions?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, refactoring, simplify

My current code:

```sh
while read -r rbv_line || [[ -n "$rbv_line" ]]; do
  if [[ "${rbv_line}" =~ ${rbv_reg} ]]; then
    rbv_downcase="${BASH_REMATCH[0],,}" &&
      ruby_version="${rbv_downcase//[^0-9a-z\.\-]/}" &&
      ((reg_matches="${reg_matches}"+1))
    printf "\n"
    printf "Setting Ruby version: %s\n" "${ruby_version}"
    break
  fi
done < "${1}"
```

It does what I want. But I would love to know if I can simplify this code even more, hoping someone can help me understand the syntax.

If you see these two lines:

```sh
rbv_downcase="${BASH_REMATCH[0],,}" &&
  ruby_version="${rbv_downcase//[^0-9a-z\.\-]/}" &&
```

Initially I tried to combine those into one using something like this:

```sh
ruby_version="${BASH_REMATCH[0],,//[^0-9a-z\.\-]/}"
```

That does not work.

Is there a way to combine those two parameter expansions (`,,` and the `//[^0-9a-z\.\-]/`) or is passing it through an intermediary variable the right approach?

You can view the latest version of the code here:
https://github.com/octopusnz/scripts

Comment: You can't combine more than one substitution like that. If we knew what the input and expected output was we might be able to find a simpler way to extract that.

Comment: You should give input sample and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine multiple parameter expansions, but...

---

... you can simplify this code!

The biggest gain is by using already available tools.

1. Instead of looping, let's use `grep`. It's supposed to do something when RegEx pattern is occurred, so:

```sh
grep -E "$rbv_reg" "$1" # -E is for extended RegEx
```

2. I guess your pattern isn't case sensitive, so let's disable it with `-i` flag.
3. The loop breaks after match, so let's pass `-m 1` to stop processing file after first match.
4. You want to convert uppercase to lowercase, so let's pipe it through `tr`:

```sh
grep -m 1 -E -i "$rbv_reg" "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

5. You then replace some characters with `//[^0-9a-z\.\-]/`, piping it to `sed` will do the trick:

```sh
grep -m 1 -E -i "$rbv_reg" "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/[^0-9a-z\.\-]//g'
```

6. And at the very end, let's grab the output to variable:

```
ruby_version="$( grep -m 1 -E -i '$rbv_reg' '$1' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/[^0-9a-z\.\-]//g' )"
```

7. Since you are printing new line anyway, let's use simple `echo` instead of `printf`
8. All what's left is `if [ -n "$ruby_version" ]` to increment `reg_matches`

At the end, we got:

```sh
ruby_version="$(
    grep -m 1 -E -i '$rbv_reg' '$1' |
    tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
    sed 's/[^0-9a-z\.\-]//g'
)"

if [ -n "$ruby_version" ]; then
    reg_matches="$((reg_matches+1))"
    echo
    echo "Setting Ruby version: $ruby_version"
fi
```

The advantage of above code is the fact it isn't really Bash dependent and should work in any POSIX Bourne compatible shell.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, much appreciated.